# Flutter, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot is empty

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I uploaded user input data to firebase and tried to display it on the screen using stream builder. But I couldn't display the data, I tried printing the data and I got this in the terminal `[]`. This means the data is null I guess but firestore has data. How do I solve this problem?

stream

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('paymnet data')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text('Loading'),
                    );
                  }
                  print(snapshot.data!.docs);
                  return ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((data) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(data['amount']),
                    );
                  }).toList());
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Are you sure the spelling is 'paymnet data' and not 'payment data'

Comment: I'm sure. It's paymnet data

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change your **collection name** `paymnet data` to `paymentData/payment_data` set the name with without spaces...